# how turn on php_flag engine again

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use php_flag engine off in my .htaccess any anything not work anymor,I use this code :

```
php_flag engine off
```

in my .htaccess in wrong, and now I remove it but nothing open at all.
how to fix it or undo this trrible?

**EDIT    :**
I use these code is .htaccess but not help :

```
php_flag engine on
php_flag engine 1
```

I understand the problem, it was because of my host, it was free, so such thing happend.

Comment: try Empty your browser cache and restart your server

Comment: it dosn't work when I try to open with other devices nither :-|

Comment: what do you mean by restarting server?